# Setting up automated ubuntu 15.10 installation using preseed and USB

Tags: system-installation, 15.10, preseed

The ubuntu documentation on preseeding is quite vague. I am struggling to load my preseed file which is located in the root directory of my usb drive. If any one can provide me tips, links or tutorials it'd be appreciated. I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 15.10 (Wily Werewolf).

Answer (score 0):

while looking around for the 15.10 preseed entries..happened to land up at 
https://github.com/RobertCNelson/netinstall/blob/master/lib/wily-preseed.cfg
hope this helps..
In the process of testing the suggestions in above link...